# To what extent are RegEx engines compatible with one another?

Tags: regex, r, emacs, ess

I am creating regular expressions for work in R, using ESS in Emacs as my environment. R itself uses the [PCRE engine](http://www.pcre.org/), which is written in C and C++.

**Question**

I would like to know, if I send my code to somebody else, using a different version of R, perhaps in a completely different environment, will the RegEx work all the same? How often do you face an issue like this? Have you even seen one?

Logic tell me, that if the person is running my code, then they are using the same compiler etc. (of course you don't run R code in anything other than an R shell of some kind!) - however some things I have read have made me question this logic.

**My findings**

The answer may well be discernible from [this site](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/regex.html), but I don't understand enough to be certain. Here is an excerpt from StackOverflow's `regex` [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info)

> The Perl programming language featured a significantly modified and enhanced version of Henry Spencer's regular expression library. With the release of Perl v5, further enhancements including lookaheads, lookbehinds, non-committing matches, non-capturing groups etc. were introduced. Through Philip Hazel's library reimplementation PCRE, these capabilities were made available in many other programming languages, including, but not limited to, PHP, Python, and R. Hence, Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions are the third main dialect of regular expressions in widespread use.

It does seem then that PCRE is good, but should I be worried that I am in Emacs and others might read my code in a different text editor (That text goes on to mention this problem)?

**Extra Info**

*As a possible example of a [compatibility issue](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5568/why-do-regular-expressions-created-with-the-regex-builder-use-syntax-different-f):* I am using the `re-builder` function in Emacs while looking at my huge text file, so I enter my regex in a mini-buffer and the matches are highlighted in the text displayed above. I finally nailed it, pasted this regex into my R code and... boom... it didn't get the job done.
Maybe this will turn out to be an issue with the actual function I am using in R (`gsub`), but it still goes to show that compatibility issues exist. Here is the function which fails in R, but worked in Emacs' `re-builder`:

```
gsub("http:.*?[([:space:])| |\n]", "", x))
```

Comment: There won't be any construct differences if that's what you mean. Show the regex you are using.

Comment: I have added the function that includes the regex - the idea is to cut out all links in many strings. This is used within R's `sapply` function in my case.

Comment: There is your problem. This `[([:space:])| |\n]` is a single class.

Comment: That matches one character, either a space or newline or ( or ) or |

Comment: I think you may need to check your assumptions. The details of which version of the regex engine (TRE)  is used by R are in the `?regex` page. It may not be the same as used by emacs. The PCRE engine can be chosen with `perl=TRUE`, but is not the default.

Comment: Be aware that Emacs regexps are quite different from regexps in other environments.

Comment: Thanks for your comments - it motivated me to dig deeper and I managed to solve my specific problem - [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33284951/how-to-find-replace-all-urls-links-from-a-text-strings-in-r-using-regex). Through all my searching in documentation, however, I did not find the specifics of the R regex engine or a comparison of it to others. It would be great to have a table somewhere with the desired output and how to achieve it in the various engines. like they are compared side by side [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines).

Comment: I found in an [example](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) of R#s `grep` function, that **all** backslashes need to themselves be escaped within R, hence my problem.

Comment: Here's a [regex reference table](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html). You can compare R regex with all major regex flavors (browse the links on the left).