# How to find/replace all URLs/links from a text strings in R using regex

Tags: regex, r, parsing, emacs

I have a text file with `n` rows, each row being a character string.

I would like to import this into *R* and sequentially remove all URLs beginning (specifically) with `http` using regex.

The following worked within an interactive regex checker (re-builder in Emacs), but not within R.

```
gsub("http:.*?[([:space:])| |\n]", "", x))
```

**Note**

This question and my given answer below stem from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263759/to-what-extent-are-regex-engines-compatible-with-one-another) about regex engines and their compatibility with one another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is as follows:

```
output <- sapply(input, FUN = function(x) gsub("http\\S+\\s*", "", x))
```

- `sapply` performs a function ***S**imply* over each row of a data frame (in my case).
- `gsub` uses regex to find each link and removes it, by substituting it with *nothing*: `""`
- the regex: `"http\\S+\\s*"` :

  1. "http" finds all occurences of "http" within `input`
  2. "\S+" continues on from http through all none-whitespace characters
  3. "\s*" ends the search when one or more whitepace characters are found
- the trailing `x` is just the input that the function definition `FUN` points to within the `sapply` function.

I think the main take away (for me, at least) is the usage of double *backslash* within R. For example, using the following regex, I was able to remove all URLs within the Emacs interactive regex checker (Emacs command: `M-x re-builder`), but not in R:

```
"http:.*?[([:space:])| |\n]"
```

I wasn't myself sure how to do this as testing regex expressions interactively with the target text is many free [online](https://regex101.com/) [tools](http://regexpal.com/), but R uses its own flavour of regex.
It is possible to use a Perl (version 5.x) regex engine, but my answer below avoids this.

The short discussion in [this thread](http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/23082-R-quot-%5C%5C-quot-and-quot-quot-signs) may prove useful in explaining this all.

Comment: There are many answers in SO that describe the need for doubling of the backslash in R-regex pattern arguments. I suggest deleting this answer  (which will fail with https and ftp URLs) and the question, since I don't really think they add anything other than demonstrating that you didn't read `?regex` very carefully and didn't work through the examples in `?sub`.

Comment: Whilst I agree with most of what you write, I did say I only wanted URLs with http - not ftp - and I'm afraid you are wrong, it DOES work for `https`. Also, it isn't always possible for non-programmers like myself to simply read through a ?help or vignette and understand everything, especially something like regex. I think my answer serves to help someone who needs and outcome like I did. I spent a long time to find this answer, now someone else doesn't need to. It is hard to find everything on SO when you don't necessarily know what to search for. I'll adapt my OP to be clearer/more specific.